# ListView Transition with Data Binding

Tags: xaml, mvvm, data-binding, windows-phone, transition

I got this ListView commonly bound to a Observable Collection in a MVVM pattern.
The Binding is stable from the moment the Page is loaded. In the first 2-3 secs there is an async HTTP GET thing, that pulls some data and dejosn it into the Observable Collection.

Is there a way to use the standard transition mechanism and get some cool animation in to that?
For now it only appears.

I tried some XAML with the transition attribute but nothing has changed.

Comment: So you want a cool animation when the items of the collection populate the listview? Not sure I understand where and what condition would receive an animation on what part. Got some sort of an example to help visualize what you're talking about? It's most likely do-able with multiple cool animation options, but having trouble visualizing what you mean.

Comment: In a different App I used <ListView.Transition>...</ListView.Transition> to get some animation in my list. The items came out smoothly from the bottom. The different between this app and my current problem is, that the items are loaded asyncly.
I guess the animation is already been done with noe items in the list and when the data finally arrives there is no animation anymore.

Comment: If my assumptions are wrong, please correct me